# Why this slicing example doesn't work in NumPy the same way it works with standard lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Why this slicing example doesn't give the same results as standard lists? It works like if it first evaluates `an[:2] = bn[:2]` and then `bn[:2] = an[:2]`.

```
import numpy as np

l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]

a = list(l1)
b = list(l2)

an = np.array(a)
bn = np.array(b)

print(a, b)
a[:2], b[:2] = b[:2], a[:2]
print(a, b)

print(an, bn)
an[:2], bn[:2] = bn[:2], an[:2]
print(an, bn)
```

Output:

```
--------------------
[1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6]
[4, 5, 3] [1, 2, 6]
--------------------
[1 2 3] [4 5 6]
[4 5 3] [4 5 6]
--------------------
```

If I do it like this - everything works:

```
dummy = an[:2]
an[:2] = bn[:2]
bn[:2] = dummy
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For lists `a[:2]` is a copy of the list with the first two elements, for numpy arrays this is only a reference.
You need to make a copy, explicitly:

```
an[:2], bn[:2] = bn[:2].copy(), an[:2].copy()
```